# Renaming files using custom pipeline in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I tried to rename a file before sending the file to an ftp location using the SFTP adapter in BizTalk 2013. Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly did you try?  To rename a file, you have to create a custom Pipeline Component.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the FILE.ReceivedFileName property on the message to your new filename.

If you use an orchestration you can do this in an expression within a message assignment shape as follows:

```
OutboundMessage(FILE.ReceivedFileName) = "NewFileName.csv"
```

If you aren't using an orchestration you have to use a custom pipeline component. 
The code to do this within the component is as follows, which goes in the pipeline component's Execute method:

```
pInMsg.Context.Write("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties", "NewFileName.csv");
```

Finally in the SFTP adapter set the filename to %SourceFileName%

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't it better to just set the destination file name?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ, that'd be an option too, but this solution is more flexible for testing - for example, if you use a FILE adapter or FTP adapter in different environments, you can use the same properties

Answer (score 0):

I believe the URL for the context is different per adapter.

The one you need is:

SFTP:
http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2012/Adapter/sftp-properties

So in your case it would be :

pInMsg.Context.Write("ReceivedFileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2012/Adapter/sftp-properties", "NewFileName.csv");

Thx